# How to resolve reg expression in angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular6

I am trying to validate phone number in the reactive form validation. but reg expression not working properly. Getting error like below:

> ```
> ERROR
> Error: Invalid regular expression: /^/^+([0-9]{1,3})?[- ]?(d{3})?[- ]?(d{3})[- ]?(d{4,6})( ext d{4})?$/$/: Nothing to repeat
> ```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g7vtuj-onr6bz?file=app%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts

Comment: @user16967562: Not working. Please edit the stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the extra forward slashes **/** at the beginning and end of the regular expression pattern.
Also there is a typo in the regular expression; **\d** should be used instead of d for digit matching.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Which AI are you using to generate your answer?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your regular expression.

The main one is that `+` has special meaning in a regular expression and needs to be escaped. This will make the regexp valid but it still won't work.

`d{3}` will match exactly "ddd" (three literal "d" characters) to match a multiple digits you will need to use `\d{3}`.

After doing this your regular expression should look like

```js
Validators.pattern(
        '/^\\+([0-9]{1,3})?[- ]?(\\d{3})?[- ]?(\\d{3})[- ]?(\\d{4,6})( ext \\d{4})?$/'
      ),
```

Comment: Not working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g7vtuj-kfuzdy?file=app%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts,app%2Fselect-multiple-example.html

Comment: Type like :  +1 666 7777  and check it

Comment: @sarann The regular expression is now valid and that feels like a different question.

Comment: @sarann if you want help with the regular expression itself, you will need to add your requirements including examples of what will and won't match. Preferably as a separate question.

Comment: Edited my question here. So, Please try to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Validators.pattern(
/^+([0-9]{1,3})?[- ]?(\d{3})?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4,6})( ext \d{4})?$/
),

use this corrected pattern.
reported issue are as below:

1. Removed the extra ^ at the beginning and the extra $ at the end.
2. Changed d to \d for digit matching.